# How do I use list comprehension to simplify the sorting and adding of multiple lists and strings?

Tags: python, string, sorting, directory, list-comprehension

The loop below will take a list of directories and/or images, and it will return a list of images, including those images in the supplied directories. For each directory that it is given, it verifies that each file is indeed a valid image, before adding that image to the list.

```
import os
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-style_image", help="List of images and/or directories")
params = parser.parse_args()

style_image_input = params.style_image.split(',')
valid_ext, style_input_sorted = [".jpg",".png"], None
for image in style_image_input:
    if os.path.isdir(image):
        for file in os.listdir(image):
            print(file)
            ext = os.path.splitext(file)[1]
            if ext.lower() not in valid_ext:
                continue
            if style_input_sorted == None:
                style_input_sorted = file
            else: 
                style_input_sorted += "," + file
    else:
        if style_input_sorted == None:
            style_input_sorted = image
        else: 
            style_input_sorted += "," + image 
style_image_list = style_input_sorted.split(',')
print(style_image_list)
```

How can I use list comprehension to simplify this loop?

Comment: You can't. Why would you ever consider turning a 16 line long loop into a list comprehension?

Comment: Because there are repeating patterns that seem like they could allow me to simplify the code, so that it uses less lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forget about "how can I turn this into a list comprehension". Start with "how can I simplify this". If, in the end, you get down to a loop with one or two clauses and a simple expression, then you can consider turning that into a list comprehension, but that's the final step, not the starting goal.

---

Most of your repetition is in the way you're building up `style_input_sorted`:

- Set it to `None`.
- Every time you get a value, if it's `None`, set it to the value
- Otherwise, add a comma and then add the value.

Instead of starting with `None`, you *could* start with `""`, and then do this:

```
if style_input_sorted:
    style_input_sorted += ","
style_input_sorted += file
```

---

But, even more simply: what you're doing is the same thing `str.join` already knows how to do. If you can build up a *list* of strings, and then just `join` that list at the end, it'll be a lot simpler:

```
style_input_sorted = []
if …
    for …
        style_input_sorted.append(file)
else …
    style_input_sorted.append(file)
style_input_sorted = ",".join(style_input_sorted)
```

---

But it looks like the only thing you ever do with `style_input_sorted` is to split it back out into a list anyway. So why even join a string just to split it?

```
style_input_list = []
if …
    for …
        style_input_list.append(file)
else …
    style_input_list.append(file)
```

---

There are some other simplifications you can make, but this is the biggest one, and it'll open the door for the next ones. For example, now that you're only doing one trivial thing instead of four lines of code for valid extensions, you can probably get rid of the `continue`:

```
if os.path.isdir(image):
    for file in os.listdir(image):
        ext = os.path.splitext(file)[1]
        if ext.lower() in valid_ext:
            style_input_list.append(file)
else:
    style_input_list.append(file)
```

---

And now we have a piece we could turn into a list comprehension—although I'd use a generator expression:

```
if os.path.isdir(image):
    images = (file for file in os.listdir(image)
              if os.path.splitext(file)[1].lower() in valid_ext)
    style_input_list.extend(images)
else:
    style_input_list.append(image)
```

But to turn the whole thing into a list comprehension will be horribly ugly. You can turn that into an expression using ternary `if` and flatten the whole thing out at the end, but if you have five lines of code, that doesn't belong inside a comprehension. (Of course you could factor those five lines out into a function and then wrap a call to that function into a comprehension, which might be worth doing.)

Comment: Thanks for the help! The function was actually based on some Lua code that I wrote a while back when I wasn't as good at coding.